# Is it advisable to use apt-get clean twice in Dockerfile?

Tags: dockerfile, java, apt-get, apt

I am installing openjdk and python in Dockerfile. This is how it looks:

From Ubuntu:latest

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk && \
    apt-get install -y ant && \
    apt-get install -y ca-certificates-java && \
    apt-get clean && \
    update-ca-certificates -f && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer && \
    apt-get update && apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev build-essential && \
    apt-get install -y python3 && \
    apt-get clean
```

Should I use apt-get clean while installing CA certificate? I am using apt-get clean at bottom of all installation.

Answer (score 1):

It's useless to run these 2 times.  The last one is enough.

Also, the `rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` command should be moved to the end.